# Transactional Camel route marking exchange as handled based on expression not working

Tags: apache-camel

My camel route is consuming and producing from/to JMS in a transactional way. Our requirement is to discard a poison message if failing to process a number of times. I know that a much better option would be to move the message to a dead letter queue but for the purpose of this exercise discarding it is just good.

Below is the route definition to simulate the issue:

```
package com.my.comp.playground;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        onException(Exception.class)
                .process(new Processor() {
                    private int failureCounter = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("failureCounter", ++failureCounter);
                    }
                })
                .log("failureCounter = ${header.failureCounter}")
                //.handled(true);
                .handled(header("failureCounter").isGreaterThan(3));

        from("jms:test.queue")
                .routeId("test-route")
                .transacted()
                .process(exchange -> {
                    throw new RuntimeException("No good Pal!");
                })
                .to("mock:discard");
    }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is to keep a counter of the failures and if that counter is greater than a certain number mark the exception as handled and commit the transaction.

Note the two lines of code at the end of the exception handling:

```
 //.handled(true);
 .handled(header("failureCounter").isGreaterThan(3));
```

When I run my route with the `header("failureCounter").isGreaterThan(3)` handled condition the message rollbacks again and again forever, and I can see in the logs the failureCounter correctly being increased:

```
...
[mer[test.queue]] test-route                               : failureCounter = 402
[mer[test.queue]] o.a.c.p.e.DefaultErrorHandler            : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ...
...
[mer[test.queue]] test-route                               : failureCounter = 403
...
[mer[test.queue]] test-route                               : failureCounter = 404
...
```

However when I run the route with the `true` handled condition the transaction gets committed straight away after the first failure as shown below:

```
[mer[test.queue]] test-route                               : failureCounter = 1
[mer[test.queue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction commit (0x52b2f795) redelivered(true)
```

So my question is: Am I doing something wrong or is my understanding about how to use `handled` exception incorrect? If so what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea if this is by design or a bug.

When I debug your case I see that the predicate in `handled()` is evaluated against the Camel Exchange.

However, your **`failureCounter` header is not present in the Exchange**. Therefore the expression `header("failureCounter")` evaluates to `null` and your predicate is always `false`.

In a short test I saw that **headers set before the exception are present**, but headers set after the exception (i.e. set inside the error handler), are not present on the Exchange that is used to evaluate the predicate.

Comment: I don't think your statement **failureCounter header is not present in the Exchange** is true. As you can see from the log the increasing failureCounter is written to the logs. And that log is just before evaluating the handled predicate.

Comment: Yes, this is another strange point I don't really understand. This log line correctly shows the incremented value of `failureCounter`. But if you copy this log line **before** your processor, it logs only the text without the header value. It behaves such as if the increment would make the header "visible".

Comment: I debugged down into `BinaryPredicateSupport.matchesReturningFailureMessage`. There happens the evaluation of the Predicate of `handled`. The left side (`header("failureCounter")`) evaluates to null. At least in my case, I use Camel 2.x for this test by the way.

Comment: Thanks. Your comment pointed me to finding out the root cause and once understanding what was happening the solution was just easy. Will publish this as a separate response just in case someone else will be having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Burki's comments were good observations which helped me identify the root cause.

Despite the fact that camel DSL suggests the `.handled(header("failureCounter").isGreaterThan(3))` check would happen after running the failure counter increase processor and the log output in reality the `.handled` is the first thing to be evaluated in that `onException(...)` branch. It seems a bit misleading and I must admit I feel a bit disappointed with this approach. It must be a reason though.

Given camel will create a new `Exchange` for every message delivery no surprise this will rollback forever.

To address this there are two solutions that came immediately in my mind.

**Solution 1:**
It is based on the fact that the message broker will set the `JMSRedelivered` message header so it is OK to increase message counter based on that. So the new route config will look like below:

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    onException(Exception.class)
            .handled(header("failureCounter").isGreaterThan(3));

    from("jms:test.queue")
            .routeId("test-route")
            .transacted()
            .process(new Processor() {
                private int failureCounter = 0;
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    if (exchange.getIn().getHeader("JMSRedelivered", Boolean.class)) {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader("failureCounter", ++failureCounter);
                    }
                }
            })
            .log("failureCounter = ${header.failureCounter}")
            .process(exchange -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("No good Pal!");
            })
            .to("mock:discard");
}
```

After applying this change the message will be discarded after more than three consecutive failures to deliver the message as shown in the logs below:

```
46849 --- [mer[test.queue]] test-route                               : failureCounter = 4
46849 --- [mer[test.queue]] o.a.c.s.spi.TransactionErrorHandler      : Transaction commit (0x31b273b2) redelivered(true) for (MessageId: ID:414d5120514d31202020202020202020c083da5f02bd1d22 on ExchangeId: ID-C02XN27DJG5H-1608604365426-0-4))
```

**Solution 2:** This is even easier but it is message broker specific in this case IBM MQ.

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    onException(Exception.class)
            .log("failureCounter = ${header.JMSXDeliveryCount}")
            .handled(header("JMSXDeliveryCount").isGreaterThan(3));

    from("jms:test.queue")
            .routeId("test-route")
            .transacted()
            .process(exchange -> {
                throw new RuntimeException("No good Pal!");
            })
            .to("mock:discard");
}
```

And the logs will show again that the message gets delivered four times before giving up.